# Oracle database documentation mismatch

Tags: oracle

I found a mismatch in

```
Oracle® Database
Data Warehousing Guide
11g Release 2 (11.2)
E25554-02

Page 21-14
-----------------quote start----------------------------
ROLLUP(a, b, c)
And this statement is equivalent to:
GROUPING SETS ((a, b, c), (a, b), ())
-----------------quote end----------------------------

I think this statement is equivalent to:
GROUPING SETS ((a, b, c), (a, b), (a), ())
```

Indirect confirmation I found in
http://www.orafaq.com/node/56 (an article is titled 
"Enhanced Aggregation, Cube, Grouping and Rollup")

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Am I right ? :-) And how can I report this fact to Oracle?

Comment: umm, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/bugreports-140511.html#gbvge

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "bug report" on Oracle's documentation, not a question on programming.

Comment: To report documentation bug, use the feedback facility provided in the online documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I report this fact to Oracle?

**To report a bug in the Oracle documentation, you can send the feedback to the technical writing team. The feedback facility is provided in the online documentation itself.**

On the left pane of the docs, you will see the **feedback button**:

[image]

Click on the feedback button, and explain the details:

[image]

You will get a response email with required people in **TO** and **CC** list. Along with details like

- **Book Title**
- **Part number**
- **Release**
- **Topic Title**
- **URL**
- **Date**

Once you receive the email, you can continue further discussion with the respective team.

Comment: Thanks, just reported them )